# How to run one javascript function on two different events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one javascript function and I want run it on two diferent events - document.ready and window.scroll. How to do it?

Comment: what is the problem you faced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing you're using jQuery (document.ready and all).

Attaching the event handler to the window after document.ready, and then triggering the event immediately fires the handler on document.ready and on every scroll event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        // do stuff
    }).trigger('scroll');
});
```

or to reference a function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', myJavascriptFunction).trigger('scroll');
});

function myJavascriptFunction() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call it like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
           //some func
        });
        //same func
    })
```

also use it like this on [onscroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

If u want it on [doc.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) too then write 2nd time too(though its not a good idea.)